# Possible to write an HTML form in C or C++

Tags: php, c++, c, programming-languages

I use PHP and I know that PHP is written in C or uses C somehow. I'm trying to understand lower level languages. So can someone explain to me how the HTML that PHP generates (let's say the markup for a form) is built with C. Can I build a web form in C or C++ and how?

Comment: keyword is CGI. can I ask why do you want to do this?

Comment: @yi_H it's just a learning exercise to help me understand things better

Comment: There is no real befit in using C to generate web pages. Technically they may be faster but CPU speed is not your bottleneck. Higher level languages (like PHP) provide extra tools to help in page generation and don't need to be recompiled all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to write a [*Common Gateway Interface*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (aka "CGI") program in any computer language which can send text to the *standard output* channel (i.e. pretty much every one):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    printf("<pre>Hello, World!</pre>\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[html, body, etc tags omitted for brevity].

Answer (score 7):

The same way as in PHP.

Strictly speaking, "HTML form" (as well as any other HTML code) is just a block of text.
And C is good at printing texts as well as any other lahguage.

Comment: **stop upvoting this stupid answer!** I wrote a hundred others today, 100 times more useful, took me 100 times more time to write, explaining more important things but scarcely get 0. And this one keep getting up. I'd never understand this *** site.

Comment: You are welcome to delete your answer if you think it's stupid enough not to add something useful to the site.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Just make it a wiki if you don't want it to get upvoted.

Comment: It is good answer per se, as good as other my answers, but it gets upvoted disproportionately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can make the html with using c++ moreover there are some frameworks available for web development using c++
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Answer (score 2):

Just as you build them in PHP. You echo (or in C's case `printf()`) the elements on the server side, and that should be parsed by the webserver and served to the client.